# colon expected error, colons? not semicolons?

Tags: java, syntax

code:

```
import ------.*;
public class Assignment2 {

  enum Picture {BACKGROUND, LEGS, BILL, BODY, EYE}

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    //Constants
    final int SIDE = 130;
    final int SCALE = 2;

    //The array
    Picture [][] duck = new Picture [SIDE][SIDE];

    //Read in the informations
    EasyReader input  = new EasyReader("duck.txt");
    for (int r = SIDE-1; r >=0; r--) //top row first
      for (int c=0; c<SIDE; c++)  {
        int i = (int)input.readChar();
        if  ( i % 2 == 0  )
          if  ( i % 22 == 0  )
            duck[r][c] = Picture.EYE;
          else
            duck[r][c] = Picture.BACKGROUND;
          else if ( i % 7 == 0  )
            duck[r][c] = Picture.BILL;
          else if ( i % 5 == 0  )
            duck[r][c] = Picture.LEGS;
          else
            duck[r][c] = Picture.BODY;
      }

    //Display it
    EasyGraphics window = new EasyGraphics(SIDE*SCALE*2,SIDE*SCALE*2);
    //sky
    window.setColor(100, 200, 255);
    window.fillRectangle(0,SIDE*3,SIDE*SCALE*2,SIDE);
    //grass
    window.setColor(100,200,0);
    window.fillRectangle(0,SIDE,SIDE*SCALE*2,SIDE*2);
    //River
    window.setColor(0,100,100);
    window.fillRectangle(0,0,SIDE*SCALE*2,SIDE);

    //The ducks
    for (int r=0; r <SIDE; r++)
      for (int c=0; c<SIDE; c++)
        if  (  duck[r][c] != Picture.BACKGROUND ) {
          //set the colour
          switch (  duck[r][c] ) {
            case EYE -> window.setColor(0,0,0);//black
            case BILL -> window.setColor(255,0,0);//red
            case LEGS -> window.setColor(100,100,0);//brown
            case BODY -> window.setColor(200,200,0);//yellow
          }
          //top left duck
          window.fillRectangle(c*SCALE,SIDE*SCALE+r*SCALE,SCALE,SCALE);
          //bottom right duck
          if  ( duck[r][c] != Picture.LEGS )
            window.fillRectangle(SIDE*SCALE+c*SCALE,r*SCALE,SCALE,SCALE);
          //small top right duck
          window.plot(SIDE*SCALE+SIDE/2+c,SIDE*SCALE+SIDE/2+r);
          //small duck in the middle
          window.plot(2*SIDE+SIDE/2-c,SIDE+SIDE/2+r);
        }

  }

}
```

error message:

```
Assignment2.java:50: error: : expected
            case EYE -> window.setColor(0,0,0);
                                              ^
Assignment2.java:52: error: : expected
            case BILL -> window.setColor(255,0,0);
                                                 ^
Assignment2.java:54: error: : expected
            case LEGS -> window.setColor(100,100,0);
                                                   ^
Assignment2.java:56: error: : expected
            case BODY -> window.setColor(200,200,0);
                                                   ^
4 errors
```

Edit:

I'm using:
javac 11.0.13

I use atom editor and vs-code editor.

Code is one of the possible solutions to an assignment from the past given to us from the instructor. I didn't make any changes other than removing the name of the package.
I tried to compile it using terminal and I get an error message saying that I need colons for switch command but I don't understand why? Shouldn't it be semicolon?

A while ago, I've tried many ways to fix this problem.
I deleted the comments for switch command and I tried moving the comments to a new line and I've tried rewriting the commands again (only the part where the problem is) and so on. Somehow, the problem was fixed but I don't remember what it was that fixed the problem. I didn't change any code though. (I don't have that file now.)

Comment: It doesn't say that a semicolon is expected, it says that a colon is expected. The code is using the new switch expression syntax which is only available in the newest versions of Java. What version of Java are you compiling it with? (`java -version` or `javac -version` to check from the terminal.)

Comment: You have asked two questions, one about the syntax error, the other about the graphics when the program does compile. Please keep each SO question to one question.

Comment: Your source must be set to 14 or higher.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've edited it.

Comment: this is only available in 14 or higher

Comment: Thank you. I've just installed the latest version and now it works and no error either. I thought 11 was the latest version for mac os. Thank you all:)

Answer (score 1):

```
      switch (  duck[r][c] ) {
        case EYE -> window.setColor(0,0,0);//black
        case BILL -> window.setColor(255,0,0);//red
        case LEGS -> window.setColor(100,100,0);//brown
        case BODY -> window.setColor(200,200,0);//yellow
      }
```

Is a Java [switch expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) introduced in Java 12. Pre-Java-12 it would have been written is a switch statement:

```
      switch (  duck[r][c] ) {
        case EYE: window.setColor(0,0,0); break;
        case BILL: window.setColor(255,0,0); break;
        case LEGS: window.setColor(100,100,0); break;
        case BODY: window.setColor(200,200,0); break;
      }
```

Switch statements require their case labels to be followed by *a colon*.

Note that a switch expression *returns a value*, whereas a switch statement does not. Consider the following:

```java
String s = switch(i) {
  case 1 -> "one";
  case 2 -> "two";
  default -> "more";
}
```

To achieve equivalent behavior, you'd have to rewrite:

```java
String convert(int i) {
  switch(i) {
    case 1: return "one";
    case 2: return "two";
    default: return "more";
  }
}

String s = convert(i);
```

Comment: ah, I see~ will try this too! Thank you very much!